# Execute docker commands through a node js script

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-exec

Is there any better way to execute docker commands from a node js apart from using shelljs(similar packages) to execute those commands?

I have seen the package dockerode. Though it is great for some commands, it doesn't give much view on 'docker exec' command.

I just need more control while executing docker exec from nodejs which shelljs fail to provide. I want to know once the docker exec command has been executed whether it got executed successfully or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have run the command from nodejs script, use shelljs or child process to run the command and redirect the output it into a log or txt file. And the use function something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449133/javascript-check-if-txt-file-contains-string-variable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) saerch for error string in the file.

What basically happens is when you execute a docker exec within a cli, even though the error occurs that doesn't captured by shelljs. So the exit code will be 0 either way. So this causes difference in catching error in normal shell command and docker exec command.

We could make use dockerode npm package. We can use this particular [example](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/blob/master/examples/exec_running_container.js) and write it as per our use case. I just changed the code listen to the event 'data' and 'end' on the stream that returned.

Comment: Looks like he is asking for npm module. not the way to execute shell commands from nodejs

Comment: As it turns out, for many use cases, dockerode doesn't perform as well as shelljs. For example, dockerode's 'docker run' is not the same as a real 'docker run' but is a 'docker container create' followed by a 'docker container start', and some docker containers which are geared towards only working with docker run will not function with dockerode. 

Thus, suggesting shelljs is a valid solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the docker-compose npm instead:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-compose

Answer (score 2):

You can use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for the exec bash commands and get results to see success or not.

Comment: As I am running the docker exec in detached mode, I am not getting the result in shelljs. I think the same will happen f I use child_process. So is there any way to do that? I am using in detached mode because after one command execution the cli will get hang and will not execute the next commands as docker exec is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use child process for running docker commands from node js.
For example

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ls -la", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
});
```